# "Angular Way" to trigger contenteditable control from a controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, contenteditable

I have a list of items, and the current (selected) one is shown in more detail on a different part of the screen. In the more detailed part, you can edit parts of the selected item using `contenteditable`.

Now when the user adds an item to the list, I'd like to trigger the `focus` event on an element so the user can edit e.g. the title right away.

A very simplified version of what I have is this:

```
function ListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.list = [
    "one",
    "two"
  ];
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.list.push("new item");
    jQuery("li:last").trigger("focus");
  };
}
```

Using `jQuery` works in this example. Using `angular.element` fails [with](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/jqLite/nosel):

> Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!

At this point, I've familiarized myself with Angular enough to consider this usage of `jQuery` a code smell. It was written [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/473467):

> when solutioning, first "think in AngularJS"; if you can't think of a solution, ask the community; if after all of that there is no easy solution, then feel free to reach for the jQuery.

So here I am, asking the community: Is there a better way to let users edit an element right away without triggering `focus` as if the user clicked on a `contenteditable` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no better/shorter way to let users edit an element right away without triggering `focus`, so I would work on improving what you have to meet Angular's application design principles.

According to the "Angular Way", DOM manipulation must happen within a directive, business logic should be contained within controllers.

The solution is to "get the directive and controller to talk". Your example should be:

The controller:

```
function ListCtrl($scope) {
     var count = 1;
     $scope.list = [
         "one",
         "two"
     ];

     $scope.add = function() {
         $scope.list.push("new item " + count);
         $scope.$broadcast("newItemAdded");
         count++;
     };
  }
```

The directive:

```
  function ListDirective($timeout) {
      return {
           link: function(scope, element, attr) {
               scope.$on("newItemAdded", function() {
                   $timeout(function() {
                       var elements = element.find("li");
                       elements[elements.length - 1].focus();
                   });
               });
           }
      };
  }
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kxUR9/8/

Comment: Thanks. Although this extra directive is much more code, that looks more consistent to the "Angular Way."

Comment: One question though: Why do I need to wrap the `$scope.$broadcast()` call into `$timeout()`?

Comment: The `timeout` makes sure that the message is broadcast after `ng-repeat` is finished rendering, since `timeout` is executed at the end of a digest cycle, i.e. after the new item is TRULY rendered and available for manipulation by the directive. On a second look, the `timeout` would make more sense within the directive's event listener, rather than in the controller, since it is DOM-related. I will update the code in the example and JsFiddle.